# javascript - get next day of a string

Tags: javascript, date

I've a var **example = "05-10-1983"**

How I can get the "next day" of the string **example**?

I've try to use Date object...but nothing...

Comment: Is the string always going to be in MM-DD-YYY format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would do it for simple scenarios like the one you have:

```
var example = '05-10-1983';
var date = new Date();
var parts = example.split('-');
date.setFullYear(parts[2], parts[0]-1, parts[1]); // year, month (0-based), day
date.setTime(date.getTime() + 86400000);
alert(date);
```

Essentially, we create an empty [Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) and set the year, month, and date with the [`setFullYear()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setFullYear.asp) function. We then grab the timestamp from that date using [`getTime()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getTime.asp) and add 1 day (86400000 milliseconds) to it and set it back to the date using the [`setTime()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setTime.asp) function.

If you need something more complicated than this, like support for different formats and stuff like that, you should take a look at the [datejs library](http://www.datejs.com/) which does quite a bit of work for you.

Comment: Is there a leap year/second problem with using `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);`?

Comment: Is your code available with the example date in DD-MM-YYYY or MM-DD-YYYY format? I think it is MM-DD-YYYY format but I also want to confirm with you.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

```
var nextDay;
var example = "05-10-1983";

nextDay = new Date(example);
nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
```

`#getDate`/`#setDate` gets/sets the current day of the month (1-31).

After the above is run, `nextDay` will be set to whatever tomorrow's date is. This will also rollover to the next month / year if it's the end of the month, and even handle leap years. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
new Date(+new Date('05-10-1983'.replace(/-/g,'/')) + 24*60*60*1000)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the +86400000 approach is the potential for error when crossing a daylight savings time barrier.
For example, I'm on EST.
If I do this:

```
var d = new Date("11/04/2012 00:00:00");
var e = new Date(d.getTime() + 86400000);
```

e is going to be 11/4/2012 23:00:00
If you then extract just the date portion, you get the wrong value.  I recently hit upon this issue while writing a calendar control.

this will do it better (and with a flexible offset which will let you do more than 1 day in the future):

```
function getTomorrow(d,offset) {
    if (!offset) { offset = 1 }
    return new Date(new Date().setDate(d.getDate() + offset));
}
```

Comment: Your solution would roll back to the beginning of the month if **d+offset** crosses month boundaries, but **Date()+offset** does not. You need to anchor the new base date to which you add days to your original date.

So instead of:

`new Date(new Date().setDate(d.getDate() + offset));`

it should be:


`new Date(new Date(d.getTime()).setDate(d.getDate() + offset));`

Otherwise, you do the arithmetic with relation to the month of the current Date() + offset, not the d Date given in the function argument + offset.

Answer (score 2):

So

```
var d = new Date("11/04/2012 00:00:00");
var e = new Date(d.getTime() + 86400000);
```

doesn't work because of daylight saving barriers. I ran into the same problem. I ended up doing something like this:

```
function next_day(date) {
  var e = new Date(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  if e.getHours() != date.getHours() {
    e = new Date(e.getTime() + (e.getHours() - date.getHours()) * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  }
  return e;
}
```

Comment: Haven't tested it, but it's an interesting solution for the DST problem that I didn't think of. I can't think of any other scenarios where this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out day index by `getDay()` function and create an array of days strings in following manner-

```
day = new Date(YourDate);

var dayArray = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

day = dayArray[day.getDay()+1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  framework called php.js. Google for it. This includes the advanced date functions and more

Comment: This is pretty straightforward to do with navtive js, I wouldn't go straight to another "framework."

Answer (score 0):

There are leap seconds, leap days, DST, etc., so this can be a tricky problem to solve in all cases.

In my opinion, the best way to address this (without a date library) is to take advantage of the Date constructor overflow feature[1]:

```js
main();

function main() {
  var date = uniqueDateParse( '05-10-1983' );
  var newDate = nextDay( date );

  print( date );
  print( newDate );
}

function uniqueDateParse( string ) {
  var stringArray = string.split( '-', 3 );
  var month = stringArray[ 0 ],
      day   = stringArray[ 1 ],
      year  = stringArray[ 2 ];
  // Per ISO 8601[2], using Pacific Daylight Time[3].
  var dateString = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T00:00:00-07:00';
  return new Date( dateString );
} 

function nextDay( date ) {
  return new Date( date.getFullYear()
                 , date.getMonth()
                 , date.getDate() + 1 );
}

function print( object ) {
  console.log( object );
}
```

### Links

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters

[2] http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

[3] http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/pdt

Answer (score 0):

```
const today = new Date('2024-01-09') // get today's date
const tomorrow = new Date(today)
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1) // Add 1 to today's date and set it to tomorrow
console.log("Tomorrow is", tomorrow.toDateString())
```