# Javascript adding 1 to a date

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this function to get the `mm/dd/yy` of tomorrow using javascript:

```
(dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (dt.getDate() +1 ) + "/" + dt.getFullYear()
```

Todays date is 9/12/19 and the code above returns 9/13/19. However, I am not sure what this code returns on the day of `9/30/2019`. I am not sure how to test this scenario. Does this return `10/1/2019` or does it return `9/31/2019` which is incorrect.

Comment: You can create a specific date and try it yourself to find out:  `dt = new Date(2019, 8, 30)`  (month numbers in JS start at 0, so use 8, not 9).  I would encourage you to update your question to "how can I test this scenario", rather than "what is the result of this scenario".  It's the difference between being given a fish to eat, and taught how to catch a fish.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date

Comment: @jned29 The +1 for the months is because in JavaScript months are zero-based.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript, get date of the next day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081158/javascript-get-date-of-the-next-day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest approach is to just get a date object and add 1 day. It will roll over correctly to the next month:

```js
const date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

console.log(`${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getDate()}/${date.getFullYear()}`);
```

To test the end of month scenario:

```js
const date = new Date(2019, 8, 30); // September 30
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

console.log(`${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getDate()}/${date.getFullYear()}`);
```

The formatting you require corresponds to the format for the English locale, so you could also just use that instead of formatting manually:

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en', {day: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'}));
```