# How to get next two days date (day after tomorrow's date) a value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
const today = new Date()
const tomorrow = new Date(today)
const newDate = tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2)
console.log(newDate.toLocaleDateString('en-us'))
```

I'm trying to get next 2 days date with mm/dd/yyyy format, but getting issues.
I tried with following code:

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US'));
```

Example: today's date >> 6/1/2022

Expected result : 6/3/2022

Comment: So you tried _nothing_, and that didn't work? It's not terribly surprising.

Comment: check this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081158/javascript-get-date-of-the-next-day

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript, get date of the next day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081158/javascript-get-date-of-the-next-day)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact, `.setDate` does not return a Date Object, but instead modifies the Date Object you call it on.

This means, `tomorrow` will be modified by calling `.setDate`.

Just change your code to the following, to get the expected result:

```js
const today = new Date()
const tomorrow = new Date(today)
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2)
console.log("today:", today.toLocaleDateString('en-US'))
console.log("in two days:", tomorrow.toLocaleDateString('en-us'))
```