# jQuery get today's date plus x?

Tags: jquery, date

I need to be able to get a date a certain amount more than today.

For example today is 28th May, I need to have 28th May + 1 to display 29th May. 
Right now I am using:

```
var date = new Date();
document.write(date.getDate() + 1);
```

Which works fine, however when it gets to the end of the month, say the 31st, instead of showing the 1st June it will show the 32nd May, which obviously isn't right.

How can I get tomorrows date, and have it correctly reset for the next month?

Thanks :)

Comment: You should have a look at this solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1160871/1719752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're doing simple addition on the int you get from `getDate`.

If you use javascript's `Date` object, however, it'll handle this internally:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(32); // this will automatically roll over to next month
```

Thus:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

document.write(date.getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = new Date(),
    myDate = now.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24;//Timestamp + 1 day
document.write(myDate.getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(noOfdays)
{
    var x = new Date(this.valueOf());
    x.setDate(x.getDate() + noOfdays);
    return x;
}

var x = new Date();
alert(x.addDays(1))
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MCzJ6/96/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just use the 'setDate' function as shown below:

```
var date = new Date(2015, 6, 31);
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```